# If $a+b\mid a^4+b^4$ then $a+b\mid a^2+b^2$; $a,b,$ are positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Is it true: $a+b\mid a^4+b^4$ then $a+b\mid a^2+b^2$?

Somehow I can't find counterexample nor to prove it. I try to write it $a=gx$ and $b=gy$ where $g=\gcd(a,b)$ but didn't help. It seems that there is no $a\ne b$ such that $a+b\mid a^4+b^4$. Of course, if we prove this stronger statement we are done. Any idea?

Comment: There are many $a\neq b$ such that $a+b\mid a^4+b^4$. Example: $(a,b)=(5,20)$.

Comment: The forms $a=p(p+q), b=q(p+q)$ have $a+b=(p+q)^2$ and this clearly divides $a^4+b^4$.

Comment: This is one of those problems where it is helpful to have the computer try to generate some counterexamples.  In this case it generates many, which resolves the conjecture immediately, and then you can look at the generated examples to see if there is anything suggestive about them.  In this case you might notice right away that none of the counterexample pairs is relatively prime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well,

\begin{align}
&& a+b &\mid a^4 + b^4 \\
&\iff & a+b &\mid a^4 + b^4 - (a+b)^4 + 4ab(a+b)^2 \\
&\iff & a+b &\mid 2a^2b^2 \\
&\iff & a+b &\mid ab\bigl((a+b)^2 - (a^2+b^2)\bigr) \\
&\iff & a+b &\mid ab(a^2+b^2)\,
\end{align}

so for coprime $a,b$ it follows that $a+b \mid a^4+b^4 \iff a+b \mid a^2+b^2$.

Writing $a = gx,\, b = gy$ with $g = \gcd(a,b)$, we see that $a+b \mid a^4 + b^4$ if and only if $x+y \mid g^3(x^2+y^2)$, and $a+b \mid a^2+b^2$ if and only if $x+y \mid g(x^2+y^2)$. So if we find coprime $x,y$ and a $g$ such that $x+y \nmid g(x^2+y^2)$ but $x+y \mid g^3(x^2+y^2)$, we have a counterexample.

Choosing $x = 1,\, y = 7$ and $g = 2$ provides one, $1+7 = 8 \nmid 100 = 2(1+7^2)$, but $8 \mid 400$. So

$$(2+14) \mid 2^4 + 14^4\qquad\text{and}\qquad 2+14 \nmid 2^2 + 14^2.$$

Comment: $ab(a^2+b^2) = xyg^4(x^2+y^2)$, and $a+b = g(x+y)$ divides that if and only if $x+y$ divides $xyg^3(x^2+y^2)$. Since $x+y$ is coprime to $x$ and to $y$, it follows that $x+y \mid xyg^3(x^2+y^2) \iff x+y\mid g^3(x^2+y^2)$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $$a^4+b^4=(a+b)(a^3-a^2b+ab^2-b^3)+2b^4$$ so if $a+b$ is a factor of $a^4+b^4$ it is also a factor of $2b^4$ and (by symmetry) $2a^4$

If the highest common factor of $a$ and $b$ is $y$ so that $a=py$ and $b=qy$ we find that $(p+q)y$ is a factor of $2q^4y^4$. Now $p+q$ can have no factor in common with $q$ by construction, so $p+q|2y^4$. We find an easy solution by setting $p+q=y$.

You might want to think about constructing a counterexample before going further, by tightening things up a bit.

> If we want to be tight against a constraint we might try $y^4=\frac {p+q}2$. With $y=2$ this would give $p+q=32$. Then $a=2p$ and $b=2q$ and $a^4+b^4=16 (p^4+q^4)$ and this is divisible by $p+q=32$ because $p$ and $q$ have the same parity. But now put $p=1, q=31$ with $a=2, b=62$ and $a^2+b^2=4+3844=3848$ is not divisible by $32$.

Answer (score 0):

A little handwavy but enough to get a counter example.

It's easy to verify $a+b|a^{2k} - b^{2k}$ (by noting $\frac {a^m - b^m}{a-b} = a^{m-1}+ a^{m-2}b+ ... + ab^{m-2} + b^{m-1}$ and replacing $b$ with $-b$ and noting $(-b)^{2k} = b^{2k}$.)

$a + b|a^4 - b^4$ and $a+b|a^2 - b^2$

so if $a+b|a^4 + b^4$ then $a+b|(a^4+b^4)\pm (a^4 - b^4)$ so $a+b|2a^4$ and $a+b|2b^4$.

If $a+b|a^2 + b^2$ then by the same argument $a+b|2a^2$ and $a+b|2b^2$

So for a counter example we need $a+b|2a^4,2b^4$ but not $a+b|2a^2,2b^2$.

One way to do that would be there were a common factor, $p$, of $a$ and $b$ with $a+b|p^4$ but $p^4$ not dividing  $a$ or $b$.

That's easy enough to find once we understand what we are looking for.

Example: Let $p=3$ we want $a+b|3^4=81$ and $3$ but no higher power  divides $a$ and $b$.  To keep it simple, let $a+b = 81$ and $a=6$ and $b=75$.

That *should* do it and indeed:

$6^4 + 75^4 = 3^4(2^4 + 25^4) = (6+75)(2^4 + 25^4)$ whereas

$6^2 + 75^2 = 3^2(2^2 + 25^2)=3^2(4 + 625)=3^2*629$.  And $3\not \mid 629$ so $3^4|3^2*629$.